# Why does Chrome display "Managed by Organisation"?

Tags: malware, web-browser, chrome, corporate-policy

My wife inadvertently clicked on a flash player update and suddenly my chrome browser displays that it is being managed by an Organisation.
I tried deleting chrome and reinstalling it but nothing changed.
Could this be a malicious attempt to hijack my browser?

Comment: This is no malware removal forum, i.e. your question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

The chrome notification *Managed by your organisation* is not necessarily even a bad sign.

There are many possibilities why Chrome displays this message.

You can have a look at `chrome://policy` to find the causing policies.

For example, a plain Chrome installation from the Fedora 32 repo has the flag *AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist* activated for Single-Sign-On by default which leads to the same notification.